# Select one or more pixels on a picture with asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First of, I'm not very familiar with asp.net mvc, so I'm sorry if my question is trivial.

So I have a picture:

```
<img src=@ViewBag.CurrentImage id="imageClick" />
```

Where you should be able to select one or more pixels on this picture.
I have this javascript which gets the pixels

```
$(function () {
    $("#imageClick").click(function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
        alert(Math.floor(relativeX) + ':' + Math.floor(relativeY));
    });
});
```

In the end, there should be a "Save" button which saves the pixels that was chosen (sends it to a controller so I can save it to the db).

My initial thought (since I'm not that good with javascript) was to send all the info to the controller which holds a list of selected pixels like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#imageClick").click(function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
        @(((HomeController) ViewContext.Controller).SaveCoord(relativeX,relativeY))
    });
});
```

But obviously this didn't work..

I'm not sure what the best approach for this is, and I hope some of you can help me.

Comment: Maybe show us your controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need your send datа to controller by means of **Ajax** for example:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("SaveCoord")',
   type: "POST", 
   dataType: "json",
   data: { relativeX,relativeY}
   ...
});
```

Read more about this approach.

Comment: Ah thanks, i looked into your suggestion and got i working. But what i didnt think about, is that everytime something in the controller is called, its on a new instance of the controller. So my list (as a field) of selected pixels is getting reset everytime i press somewhere on the image...  Do you have any suggestions to get around this problem?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you have a problem, but I can assume that it is stateful, you can use Static fields or any other way for saving  your data (database, session e.t.c)